# Allocating memory for pointers inside structures in functions

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct

Let's say I declare a structure as it follows:

```
typedef struct {
    int *numbers;
    int size; // Size of numbers once treated as array
} sstruct;
```

And I create in `main()` a pointer to structure (in order to later pass it by reference) using `sstruct *example;`.

Then I have a function, call it `allocpositions()`, in which I pretend to allocate memory positions for the `*p` pointer contained in `*example`.

If I would want to allocate positions to `*example`, it would be enought to pass the direction `&example` to the function, that would receive it as `**a` and then do something like `a = (sstruct **)malloc(N*sizeof(sstruct *))`, but I don't see how I can allocate directly to `*p` inside the function.

And once allocated, would I still be able to refer the elements in `*p` as `example->p[index]` inside `allocpositions()`?

I'd appreciate any help!

**edit**

Example code illustrating what I try to achieve:

```
typedef struct {
    int *numbers;
    int size; // size of numbers once treated as array
} ssm;

main() {
    ssm *hello;
    f_alloc(&hello);
}

void f_alloc(ssm **a) {
    // Here I want to allocate memory for hello->p
    // Then I need to access the positions of hello->p that I just allocated
}
```

Comment: I am not getting what you want to achieve. Could you please rephrase your question a bit? And what have you tried so far? Please show us more code.

Comment: Give the function code, it's too complex to understand

Comment: Just added a more illustrative example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code with comments:

```
void f_alloc(ssm **a) {

    *a = malloc(sizeof(ssm)); // Need to allocate the structure and place in into the *a - i.e. hello in main
    (*a)->p = malloc(sizeof(int)); // Allocate memory for the integer pointer p (i.e. hello ->p;
}
```

**EDIT**

I think this is what you are requiring:

```
void f_alloc(ssm **a, unsigned int length) {

    *a = malloc(sizeof(ssm)); // Need to allocate the structure and place in into the *a - i.e. hello in main
    (*a)->p = malloc(sizeof(int) * length); // Allocate memory for the integer pointer p (i.e. hello ->p;
    (*a)->v = length; // I am assuming that this should store the length - use better variable names !!!
}
```

Then a function to set/get

```
bool Set(ssm *s, unsigned int index, int value) {
   if (index >= s->v) {
       return false;
   }
   s->p[index] = value;
   return true;
}

bool Get(ssm *s, unsigned int index, int *value) {
   if (index >= s->v) {
       return false;
   }
   *value = s->p[index];
   return true;
}
```

I leave doing the free bit to the reader.

**EDIT 2**

As I am in a good mood.

```
void Resize(ssm**a, unsigned int new_length)
{
   (*a)->p = relloc((*a)->p, sizeof(int) * new_size);
   (*a)->v = new_length;
}
void Free(ssm *a)
{
   free(a->p);
   free(a);
}
```

you can make it more fault tolerant to check that `malloc/realloc` have worked

Comment: And from now on can I refer to the elements of `p` with `hello->p[index]`, or should it be `hello[0]->p[index]`?

Comment: The first piece of code (once edited) works fine for me, thank you! Could you please provide a little explanation on why are needed the functions `Get()` and `Set()`? I haven't used boolean functions before, and, even I understand what are they doing, I don't get to see why are they needed.

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge - Because they check that the index is within limits and enable the developer to report an error in the event that they are not

Comment: I understand, so it's a way of preventing accessing memory positions not allocated and avoiding possible core segmentation, right? This way, every time we access an element in `*p` we check if there are as many elements as we specified with the index.

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge - Please rename `p` and `v` to something more meaningful

Comment: Done! And one last question... Now that we have allocated both `*hello` and `*p`, let's say I want to pass `hello->p` to another function (from `f_alloc()`), `f_reall()` that will reallocate memory to `*p`. How would I achieve that?

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge - You have to write that for yourself. I have given you pointers. Write a method that performs the resize (`realloc`).

Comment: I'll get on that right now. Thank you, you have solved me a lot of doubts!

Comment: Thank you for your time! My doubt was more related to how to call this new function from inside the `f_alloc()` function. Would it be enough with `Resize(&a,number)` again?

Comment: Yes - Follow the datatypes.

Comment: Yes, but we first passed `*hello` as `&hello`, which we collected in `**a`. If now we pass `&a` won't we have something like `****a` in `Resize()`?

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge - You are passing it in the same scope as `alloc`

Comment: But I need to call `Resize()` inside `f_alloc()`, not after it.

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge - Why? You allocate it first. Then if necessary resize it.

Comment: Well, I'll try to adapt my program to the new situation.

Comment: I've been working with all your indications, and huh, I've learned a lot today! Just for fun I am trying to complicate it a little more. I am using in fact more than one structure, so instead of declaring separate pointers to them, I've declared an array, `*hello[N]`. I've had a lot of problems to adapt the code, and still didn't make it work. I don't know how to allocate now the `*p` elements...